# How to select dynamically added elements in Javascript no jquery

Tags: javascript, html

What will be best solution / practice to get dynamically added elements with Javascript?
For example I'm creating To Do app and then I add new task I get respond from backend and I append new task code to front end. But if my recently added task have so buttons I can't click them.

I could use `<div onClick=myFunction()></div>` but as far as I know it's not the best way / practice.
Also I know that in jquery you can solve this problem with this method: `$('.container').on('click', 'element', function())`. Does vanilla Js has something like this? Because I don't want to use jQuery.
Or I should after every ajax request call function which select all buttons ?

Comment: you append the new Tasks after ajax and then you put a Delete button beside each task, but the button not work ? or what's the issue ?

Comment: Yeah delete and other buttons appended with this task doesn't work